# Find a map such that $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v)$ but $T(v_1+v_2) \not= T(v_1)+T(v_2)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find a map $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that for any $v\in V$ and $\alpha\in F$,  $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v)$ but $T(v_1+v_2) \not= T(v_1)+T(v_2)$.

**Attempt** 
I tried to declare $V$ as $R^2$ and $T$ a map that multiplies by one scalar from the first and third quadrants, and another from the second and fourth quadrants. But the way I implemented it I got $T(\alpha v)\not≠\alpha T(v)$. I would love some help.

Comment: Your idea to partition the vector space and assign different scalars to each block seems good to me, maybe you should formalize your approach. By the way are there restrictions on $V$ ? For e.g. $V=\{0\}$ one cannot find a solution, neither for a one dimensional space.

Comment: There are no restrictions on V.

Comment: How about $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $T(x,y)=(x,0)$?

Comment: @Sandro But T(v1+v2)=T(v1)+T(v2)..

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Comment: What is a "linear copy"?

Comment: If you have trouble writing in English try using https://translate.google.com/ . The term "linear copy" sounds like a mistranslation.

Comment: $T_1(x,y) = (0,0)$ if $x=y$ and $(x,y)$ otherwise, i.e., the identity map except on a line where it is identical to zero. Or $T_2(\rho e^{i\theta}) = \theta \rho e^{i\theta}$ where we identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ via polar coordinates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding an additive and non-homogeneous map is trivial, but what you pose seems non-trivial (at least to me). This is what I found by doing some research, but I believe that more straightforward examples exist.

Let $V=\mathcal{S}$ be the space of sequences (you can show it is a vector space) and $x_n$ its elements. Define the map $T:V\to V$ as

$$T(x_n)=
\begin{cases}
x_n & \text{ if } x_0\neq x_1 \\
0 &\text{ if } x_0=x_1 
\end{cases}$$

This map is homogeneous because if $x_0\neq x_1$ then $T(\alpha x_n)=\alpha  x_n=\alpha T(x_n)$ by definition of $T$, and if $x_0=x_1$ then $T(\alpha x_n)=0=\alpha T(x_n)\ \forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R},\forall x_n\in\mathcal{S}$. But it is not additive, because if you take the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ defined by

$$x_n=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n=0 \\
0 &\text{ if } n\neq0 
\end{cases}$$

$$y_n=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n=1 \\
0 &\text{ if } n\neq1 
\end{cases}$$

you can see that $T(x_n)=x_n$ and $T(y_n)=y_n$, so that $T(x_n)+T(y_n)=x_n+y_n$. Yet, $x_n+y_n$ is

$$x_n+y_n=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n=0,1 \\
0 &\text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

so $T(x_n+y_n)=0$. Thus, $T(x_n+y_n)\neq T(x_n)+T(y_n)$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Exactly, in that case the partition is stable under scalar multiplication, except by $0$, but that still works well. Good answer!

Comment: To simplify the example restrict to two dimensions viz. $T(x_0\hat{e}_0+x_1\hat{e}_1)=[x_0\ne x_1](x_0\hat{e}_0+x_1\hat{e}_1)$ in terms of the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Answer (score 2):

Counter example follow OP's idea: (**Main part:**)

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ and define $T:V\to V$ as:
$$T(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(2x,2y) & \text{ if } xy>0 \\
(x,y) &\text{ if } xy<0\\
(0,0) &\text{ if } xy=0
\end{cases}$$

- $T(a(x,y))=T(ax,ay)=aT(x,y)$
- Let $v_1=(1,1)$, $v_2=(-2,1)$.
  $$T(v_1)+T(v_2)=(2,2)+(-2,1)=(0,3)$$
  $$T(v_1+v_2)=T(-1,2)=(-1,2)$$
  So $T(v_1+v_2)\neq T(v_1)+T(v_2)$.

---

I find an approach from the idea of op. The problem of his idea is that the values $T(ax,ay)=aT(x,y)$ is not "consistent" when it multiplies by one scalar $a$ on $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

We can observe that the product of $ax$ and $ay$ has the same sign with
the product of $x$ and $y$.

For $a\neq 0$,
$$(ax)(ay)>0 \iff xy>0$$
A best way is to separate into two parts $xy>0$ and $xy<0$ (and $xy=0$ this part is trivial in my examples) so that we can keep $T(ax,ay)=aT(x,y)$, i.e. in this way it is the same as op divides into 1,3 quadrants($xy>0$) and 2,4 quadrants($xy<0$).

In this sense, the attempt of op is absolutely **CORRECT**. We can use it to create at least infinitely many number of counter examples.

---

Idea of my solution:
Define a map T that fix the points in 2,4 quadrants, and the points in 1,3 quadrants(product is positive) is reflected about the x-axis. T will map the x-axis and y-axis to the origin.

The two vector is contructed as follows:
pick any $v_1$ in 1st quadrant, $v_2$ in 2nd quadrant, both have the same y-coordinate, and the x-coordinate of $v_1$ is closer to the $0$.

Then $v_1+ v_2$ is still in the 2nd quadrant, and it is fixed by the map T, so $T(v_1+ v_2)$ is in the 2nd quadrant.

But $T(v_1)$ is in the 4th quadrant, $T(v_2)=v_2$, the y-coodinate of
$T(v_1)$ is negative of $T(v_2)$, the x-coordinate of $T(v_1)$ is closer to the $0$ than $T(v_2)$. So $T(v_1)+T(v_2)$ must be in the negative part of the x-axis, and therefore $T(v_1)+T(v_2)$ is not in the 2nd quadrant.

---

One of my original counter example:

Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ and define $T:V\to V$ as:

$$T(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(x,-y) & \text{ if } xy>0 \\
(x,y) &\text{ if } xy<0\\
(0,0) &\text{ if } xy=0
\end{cases}$$

$T((0,0))=(0,0)$

$T(a(x,y))=T(ax,ay)=aT(x,y)$ since $ax \cdot ay=a^2 (xy)$, the sign of a is not important.

$T(1,1)=(1,-1)$

$T(-10,1)=(-10,1)$

$T(1,1)+T(-10,1)=(1,-1)+(-10,1)=(-9,0)$

$T( (1,1)+(-10,1) )=T( (-9,2) )=(-9,2)$

So $T( (1,1)+(-10,1) )\neq T(1,1)+T(-10,1)$

Answer (score 2):

The (harmonic mean) function $\tilde T\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$\tilde T(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2xy}{x+y}&x+y\ne0\\
0&x+y=0
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies $\tilde T(a(x,y))=a\tilde T(x,y)$ but is not additive. Edit: the codomain $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. Composite $\tilde T$ with a linear embedding $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$, e.g. $x\mapsto(x,0)$ or $x\mapsto(x,x)$, and we will get the desired map $T\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ that fits the requirements.